# Joining on numeric part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's been a while...I'd like to get your advice on the most efficient way to join on only the number part of a field that may be prefixed and/or suffixed with up to 2 letters. Here's a simplified snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
 SELECT a, b, c
 FROM table 1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.PolicyCode = t2.sPolicyID,
```

Where `t2.sPolicyID` could begin and/or end with up to 2 letters. Some examples: `TG73100`, `S7286674`, `2344506R`, etc. We only want to join to just its numeric part in between the letters, i.e. `73100`, `7286674` or `2344506` from the examples.

Could someone please advise on a simple way of doing this?

Comment: (1) Sample data.  (2) Desired results.  (3) Appropriate database tag.

Comment: It's not going to be simple and it's not going to be efficient. Better to fix your data

Comment: If the numeric-only portion has meaning separate from the rest of the field, it really should be in it's own field. But I  understand you don't always have control over such things. However, the solution here will vary _greatly_ depending on what kind of database you're using. We need to know that.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Regarding the type of database, it's MS SQL Server.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I agree 100%. OP can try to use a computed column or a materialized, indexed view to mitigate this problem in an efficiente way but the problem is still bad design

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
LEFT JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.PolicyCode =

LEFT(SUBSTRING(t2.sPolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t2.sPolicyID), 50),
     PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
     SUBSTRING(t2.sPolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t2.sPolicyID), 50)
     + 'a') -1)
```

To break this down, there are 4 main parts.

**1**: Find the position of the first number with `PATINDEX`:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @spolicyID) 

--Returns 3
```

**2**: Use `SUBSTRING()` to cut off everything before the first letter:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@spolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @spolicyID), 50) 

--Returns 123123xx
```

If we hardcoded the `3` that we know is returned from the first part, it would look like this:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@spolicyID, 3), 50) 

--50 is the number of characters to extract, set to something 
--higher than the max string length to be safe
```

Of course, we don't want to hardcode it since it can change, but that makes seeing the different functions a bit easier.

**3**: Find the position of the next letter using `PATINDEX` again:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@spolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @spolicyID), 50) + 'a')

--Returns 7 since it is looking at 123123xx
--The first x is in the 7th position
```

Note that we added an `a` onto the string.  This is because if we had a string with no letters at the end, it would throw an error as the length 0 would be returned to `SUBSTRING`.  You could add any letter or letters to the end and it would work, we are just making sure there is at least one.  Try removing the `+ 'a'` and using a string like `xx123123` to see the error.

If we hardcoded the `123123xx` from step 2 it would look like this (again just for easy example):

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', '123123xx' + 'a')
```

**4**: Use `LEFT()` to return everything before the trailing letters, leaving us with only the numbers in between:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

LEFT(SUBSTRING(@spolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @spolicyID), 50),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@spolicyID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @spolicyID), 50) + 'a') -1)

--Need to add `-1` because step 3 PATINDEX returns 7
--as the position of first trailing letter, and
--we want the 6 characters before that
```

And again hardcoded from step 2 and 3 for easy viewing:

```
DECLARE @spolicyID VARCHAR(20) = 'xx123123xx'

LEFT('123123xx', 7-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I will give the less awesome way a try, :).

Comment: @daniness I respect that

Comment: Hi @Aaron Dietz. Could you please explain what the less awesome solution does? I'm trying to work it out but am not sure what the + 'a' is for....thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: @daniness Answer updated - I also removed the awesome part since it got so long... At least it will live on in the edit history.

Comment: @AaronDietz you could create the awesome way dynamically, at least there'd be less repetition and an extra level of awesomeness.

Comment: Thank you, @AaronDietz ...this really helped me to follow and understand it...you're a genius! Thanks again!